# Meaning of "Zenith"

Tags: meaning-in-context

Looking at the dictionary I found that the world ***zenith*** means ***the point above the observer directly opposite the nadir***.

So what does it mean in the following sentence:

> ***At the age of forty-five, with a worldwide reputation and as yet unbroken string of notable successes to her credit, Carson was the
>   zenith of her career.***

Comment: It's a [metaphor](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Metaphors.pdf). _Zenith_ means 'the highest point', so this was 'the highest point' of her career. Even though she's not up in the sky; terms referring to `Up/Down` orientation are commonly applied metaphorically to abstract phenomena.

Comment: What dictionary did you look in? That's the *literal* definition, but in practice "zenith" is probably used more often in the figurative sense [*a highest point or state; culmination.*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/zenith)

Comment: @FumbleFingers [Definition of zenith](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/#word=zenith)

Comment: @pentanol: That definition simply proves my point that the figurative use is General Reference. Why would you need to ask here if you've just read [***Zenith** — and it's {**sic**} opposite, **nadir** — have been appropriated by non-astronomers and are **used to describe high and low points in non-astronomical contexts**. "The party lasted all night, but the zenith was definitely the moment when we climbed up onto the roof deck and watched the fireworks. It was all downhill from there."*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/zenith)?

Answer (score 1):

> [**Zenith**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/zenith)   *noun*
>
> the strongest or most successful period of time

The peak, the top, the apex, the acme, the pinnacle. [Nadir](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nadir?show=0&t=1401720771) is the opposite, the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

It means the highest or best point or part; the noontide.

> ***At the age of forty-five, with a worldwide reputation and as yet unbroken string of notable successes to her credit, Carson was the
>   zenith [=noontide] of her career.***

[noontide](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/noontide): the highest or best point or part: *the noontide of one's theatrical career*